# Where to ask a question about computer science and programming study advice?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What Stack Exchange site would a question like this be appropriate for?

> I'm a student in my 3rd year of college studying computer science and programming. So far I have studied a lot of stuff, but I mostly "specialize" in Java web development and Android. I've done lots of projects with Android and Spring, and I'm even going to an internship for those fields.
> Even though I like those things, I'm not sure if that's what I want to do for the rest of my life. During my 4th year, I will learn a bit more about data science and AI.
>
> So the questions are:
>
> - Do people transition from one technology and programming field to another during their careers, let's say from full stack developer to data science?
> - How many things can I do at once. I know I can pretty much work on both Java web projects and Android. Should I even try to incorporate another language/technology, lets say should I try and incorporate data science as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 2 is likely to be off-topic on all Stack Exchange sites. It will depend mostly on you; on your experience, talent, motivation, etc. It's best to discuss this with the person in your college responsible for student's personal development.

Question 1: the answer is (obviously) yes, but I don't really think there's an appropriate site for it either. An extreme example: even if "What is 1+1?" is about Mathematics, it's not really appropriate for Mathematics Stack Exchange because it's too basic. If you have a *specific* example you want to ask about, it's already somewhat better: consider this question on Data Science Stack Exchange: [Career switch to Big Data Analytics](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/1216/25180) which is quite well-received.

See also [Can I ask "Professional Careers and Advice" questions here?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/46/33983) on The Workplace Meta - career questions generally aren't a good fit for Stack Exchange's Q&A format.